PPO agent is not learning
I'm trying to train the model that selects the maximum number in the list of 10 numbers.
For example, I have a list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].
Given that input, the model is supposed to find the highest number, which is 9 in that case.
I have the following reward/penalty rules:

+10 if the model's answer was correct.
-1 if the model's answer was wrong.

I let my model play that game, and the accuracy is always around 10%, which is the same as just using a complete random picking.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:
import random

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from tensordict import TensorDict
from tensordict.nn import TensorDictModule, InteractionType
from torch import optim
from torch.distributions import Categorical
from torchrl.modules import ProbabilisticActor, ValueOperator
from torchrl.objectives import ClipPPOLoss
from torchrl.objectives.value.functional import generalized_advantage_estimate


def main():
    seed = 3
    torch.manual_seed(seed)

    # Find the maximum number in the list of 10 numbers.
    policy_network = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(10, 64),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(64, 10)
    )
    policy_module = TensorDictModule(
        module=policy_network,
        in_keys=["numbers"],
        out_keys=["logits"]
    )
    actor = ProbabilisticActor(
        module=policy_module,
        in_keys=["logits"],
        out_keys=["action"],
        distribution_class=Categorical,
        default_interaction_type=InteractionType.RANDOM,
        return_log_prob=True
    )
    value_network = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(10, 64),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(64, 1)
    )
    value_operator = ValueOperator(
        module=value_network,
        in_keys=["numbers"],
        out_keys=["value"]
    )
    loss_module = ClipPPOLoss(
        actor_network=actor,
        critic_network=value_operator
    )
    loss_module.set_keys(
        advantage="advantage",
        value_target="value_target",
        value="value",
        action="action",
        sample_log_prob="sample_log_prob"
    )

    # Training

    episode = 0
    max_episode = 1000
    optimizer = optim.Adam(list(policy_network.parameters()) + list(value_network.parameters()))
    number_of_correct_decisions = 0
    while episode < max_episode:
        # Generate a list of 10 random integers.
        numbers = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(10)]
        current_tensor_dict = TensorDict({
            "numbers": torch.FloatTensor(numbers)
        }, batch_size=[])
        actor(current_tensor_dict)
        max_index = current_tensor_dict["action"].item()
        value_operator(current_tensor_dict)
        current_tensor_dict["sample_log_prob"] = current_tensor_dict["sample_log_prob"].detach()
        next_tensor_dict = TensorDict({
            "numbers": torch.FloatTensor(numbers)
        }, batch_size=[])
        value_operator(next_tensor_dict)

        correct_index = numbers.index(max(numbers))

        # Reward/Penalty Rules
        score = 0
        if max_index == correct_index:
            score += 10
            number_of_correct_decisions += 1
        else:
            score -= 1
        reward = torch.FloatTensor([[score]])

        # Note that we need to use batched input and the output will be in batched form.
        advantage, value_target = generalized_advantage_estimate(
            gamma=0.98,
            lmbda=0.95,
            state_value=current_tensor_dict["value"].unsqueeze(0),
            next_state_value=next_tensor_dict["value"].unsqueeze(0),
            reward=reward,
            done=torch.BoolTensor([[1]]),
            terminated=torch.BoolTensor([[1]])
        )
        current_tensor_dict["advantage"] = advantage.squeeze(0)
        current_tensor_dict["value_target"] = value_target.squeeze(0)
        loss_tensor_dict = loss_module(current_tensor_dict)
        loss_critic = loss_tensor_dict["loss_critic"]
        loss_entropy = loss_tensor_dict["loss_entropy"]
        loss_objective = loss_tensor_dict["loss_objective"]
        loss = loss_critic + 0.01 * loss_entropy + loss_objective
        print(
            f"episode: {episode}, score: {score}, numbers: {numbers}, max_num: {numbers[max_index]}")
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        episode += 1
    print(f"Accuracy = {number_of_correct_decisions / max_episode}")

main()


It turns out that the agent did not explore enough before it was optimized.
I misunderstood the PPO concept, thinking that a negative reward would reduce the probability of selecting that action.
However, I realized that the absolute magnitude of the reward did not matter.
What matters is the relative differences among rewards.
For example, repeatedly receiving a -1 reward only makes the agent think the current action is optimal.
In other words, optimizing the model in that situation only encourages the agent to take that action.
The agent would change the action only after experiencing different rewards.
So, I learned that letting the agent experience various rewards is essential before optimization.
About the code, I changed the following:

Optimize the model once every 100 epochs so that the agent explores enough.
Use fixed numbers for the list because random numbers are difficult (even though possible) to fit using neural networks.
Use the loss_entropy from ClipPPOLoss without multiplying it by 0.01. The motivation is to increase the randomness of the action and encourage exploration.

Here is the updated code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from tensordict import TensorDict
from tensordict.nn import TensorDictModule, InteractionType
from torch import optim
from torch.distributions import Categorical
from torchrl.modules import ProbabilisticActor, ValueOperator
from torchrl.objectives import ClipPPOLoss
from torchrl.objectives.value.functional import generalized_advantage_estimate


def main():
    seed = 3
    torch.manual_seed(seed)

    # Find the maximum number in the list of 10 numbers.
    policy_network = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(10, 64),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(64, 10)
    )
    policy_module = TensorDictModule(
        module=policy_network,
        in_keys=["numbers"],
        out_keys=["logits"]
    )
    actor = ProbabilisticActor(
        module=policy_module,
        in_keys=["logits"],
        out_keys=["action"],
        distribution_class=Categorical,
        default_interaction_type=InteractionType.RANDOM,
        return_log_prob=True
    )
    value_network = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(10, 64),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(64, 1)
    )
    value_operator = ValueOperator(
        module=value_network,
        in_keys=["numbers"],
        out_keys=["value"]
    )
    loss_module = ClipPPOLoss(
        actor_network=actor,
        critic_network=value_operator
    )
    loss_module.set_keys(
        advantage="advantage",
        value_target="value_target",
        value="value",
        action="action",
        sample_log_prob="sample_log_prob"
    )

    # Training

    epoch = 0
    max_epoch = 5000
    optimizer = optim.Adam(list(policy_network.parameters()) + list(value_network.parameters()))
    number_of_correct_decisions = 0
    total_loss = 0
    numbers = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    while epoch < max_epoch:
        current_tensor_dict = TensorDict({
            "numbers": torch.FloatTensor(numbers)
        }, batch_size=[])
        actor(current_tensor_dict)
        max_index = current_tensor_dict["action"].item()
        value_operator(current_tensor_dict)
        current_tensor_dict["sample_log_prob"] = current_tensor_dict["sample_log_prob"].detach()
        next_tensor_dict = TensorDict({
            "numbers": torch.FloatTensor(numbers)
        }, batch_size=[])
        value_operator(next_tensor_dict)

        correct_index = numbers.index(max(numbers))

        # Reward/Penalty Rules
        score = 0
        if max_index == correct_index:
            score += 10
            number_of_correct_decisions += 1
        else:
            score -= 1
        reward = torch.FloatTensor([[score]])

        # Note that we need to use batched input, and the output will be in batched form.
        advantage, value_target = generalized_advantage_estimate(
            gamma=0.98,
            lmbda=0.95,
            state_value=current_tensor_dict["value"].unsqueeze(0),
            next_state_value=next_tensor_dict["value"].unsqueeze(0),
            reward=reward,
            done=torch.BoolTensor([[1]]),
            terminated=torch.BoolTensor([[1]])
        )
        current_tensor_dict["advantage"] = advantage.squeeze(0)
        current_tensor_dict["value_target"] = value_target.squeeze(0)
        loss_tensor_dict = loss_module(current_tensor_dict)
        loss_critic = loss_tensor_dict["loss_critic"]
        loss_entropy = loss_tensor_dict["loss_entropy"]
        loss_objective = loss_tensor_dict["loss_objective"]
        loss = loss_critic + loss_entropy + loss_objective
        total_loss += loss
        print(f"episode: {epoch}, score: {score}, max_num: {numbers[max_index]}")
        # It's important to let the agent explore the environment enough so that it can experience the rewards.
        # That's why we optimize the models once every 100 epochs.
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            total_loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            total_loss = 0
        epoch += 1
    print(f"Accuracy = {number_of_correct_decisions / max_epoch}")

main()

